# How can I get a location's name more detailed in Android?

Tags: java, android, google-maps, gmsmapview

I'm working a project that request me develop a tracing app. This app will automatically record app users’ traces and the app can identify a user’s activity location, including work place, home and frequently visited locations
such as grocery store. Now i can get the street name, city name and zip code by using geocoder. That's not enough for me, I want get a place name like xxx Medical Center, 123 Green St to help me identify a user’s activity location. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider using the [Places API for Android](https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/), which can help you get locations beyond what a geocoder gives you.

Comment: Thank u, I'll check it out.